# Replicación Master / slave - MySql

Tags: mysql, replication

I have slave setup and looks like it is running fine.

But does not replicate.

My Master is an IP of my Hosting and my slave in my Remote Server.

**My BD master:**

```
Variable    Valor
File    mysqld-bin.000019
Position    120
Binlog_Do_DB    asistencias,caja,colegios,intranet,intranet2,papeletas,planillas,postulacion,resoluciones,visitas
Binlog_Ignore_DB    mysql,test,app_convoca,intranetugel,moodle_ugel04,postfix,root_cwp,roundcube
```

**My slave:**

```
Variable    Valor
Slave_IO_State  Waiting for master to send event
Master_Host xxx.xx.xx.xxx
Master_User esclavo_hosting
Master_Port 3306
Connect_Retry   60
Master_Log_File mysqld-bin.000019
Read_Master_Log_Pos 120
Relay_Log_File  DB-01-relay-bin.000003
Relay_Log_Pos   284
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysqld-bin.000019
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
Replicate_Do_DB 
Replicate_Ignore_DB 
Replicate_Do_Table  
Replicate_Ignore_Table  
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table 
Last_Errno  0
Last_Error  
Skip_Counter    0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos 120
Relay_Log_Space 621
Until_Condition None
Until_Log_File  
Until_Log_Pos   0
Master_SSL_Allowed  No
Master_SSL_CA_File  
Master_SSL_CA_Path  
Master_SSL_Cert 
Master_SSL_Cipher   
Master_SSL_Key  
Seconds_Behind_Master   0
```

Show connected slaves

```
Mostrar esclavos conectados 
ID del servidor Servidor
1
```

**But it does not replicate**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find the flowchart that explains what happens when you have a mixture of `binlog_do_...` and `binlog_ignore_...` -- it is not necessarily what you would expect.

Be aware that

```
USE db1;
INSERT INTO db2.tbl
```

uses `db1`, not `db2` for determining whether to replicate.

Which binlog format are you using?

For further debugging, use mysqldumpbinlog to see if a particular row was inserted into the `binlog` file on the Master and/or whether it arrived in the `relay-log` file on the Slave.